# TRACE log level

Tags: java, log4j

I know following log levels in Log4J:

```
ALL < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF
```

But in some samplers I found TRACE

and `trace()` metod:

```
Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
LOG.trace("Instance created of AnotherClass");
```

In my IDE method `trace()` is not recognizable. Is this old Log4J library and `TRACE` appears only in some new one?

Comment: Its between ALL and DEBUG.

Comment: @user1501700 You need to update the version in order to get the TRACE level.

Comment: @user1501700 You forgot to upvote. Also accept an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`org.apache.log4j.Level.TRACE`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html#TRACE) level was added to log4j in the version 1.2.12

You need to [update](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22log4j%22%20AND%20a:%22log4j%22) the version of your log4j's library.

Comment: in Log4J, see `org.apache.log4j.Level`,  ALL=TRACE=DEBUG  syslogEquivalent is 7

Answer (score 9):

Log4j itself does not have the `TRACE` level. That log level is provided by the newer logging facades like `commons-logging` or `slf4j`. These facades itself do not log but delegate to underlying logging providers like `log4j` or `logback`.

Answer (score 3):

you have to mention it on your **log4j2-test.xml**

```
<Loggers>
<Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace">
  <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Logger>
<Root level="error">
  <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Root>
```

You have to give your logger level as trace if you want to log the traces

Refer this 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity